# Does anyone know how to add a gradient background to CupertinoSliverAppBar?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-cupertino

I am trying to add a gradient background to a `CupertinoSliverAppBar` in a Flutter app but I cannot seem to figure out how to do it. The `SliverAppBar` has a `flexibleSpace` property that would accept a gradient but the `CupertinoSliverAppBar` only has a `backgroundColor` property.

Alternatively, if it were possible to move the title in the `flexibleSpace` more to the left, I could go with that. But I cannot figure that out either.

I read these:

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25144
- [Gradient in SliverAppBar (Flutter)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52931683/gradient-in-sliverappbar-flutter?noredirect=1#comment98735141_52931683)

And this issue opened on the Flutter repository: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25144

@rmtmckenzie does the trick! It is worth noting this also works with `CupertinoSliverNavigationBar`. Also, all transition animations are preserved except for that of the background for which you will bee seeing the `backgroundColor` property being animated. You can cheat by using one of the gradient's colors as the `backgroundColor` but it is not perfect. The gradient is indeed rendered below the content. See below:

[image]

Comment: @rmtmckenzie any ideas ?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/gradientscaffoldwidget  CupertinoPageGradientScaffold method.

Comment: Also, I wanted to know if we can add an image background to Cupertino sliver nav bar?? Anyone?

Comment: @NithinSai I have created a PR for that (and gradient): https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/33177. It still needs a little cleanup to pass the tests

Comment: @Benjamin that's a great idea! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a bit difficult - as you mentioned the CupertinoSliverAppBar doesn't support 'flexibleSpace' or anything like it, so you're stuck with trying to use the backgroundColor which doesn't do what you need either.

I'd recommend opening an issue on the Flutter repo stating that it isn't possible and why you'd like to do it. They probably won't take action on it right away but if they're aware that people would like to do it it, it might happen.

Not all hope is lost for an immediate fix though, we can cheat! (although I'm hoping you'll use a less terifyingly ugly gradient when you write your version)

[image: screenshot showing cupertinoappbar with gradient][image: screenshot showing cupertionoappbar collapsed with gradient]

What I've done is subclassed Border, and then overridden what it draws so that it draws a gradient you pass in before drawing the actual border. This works because it's given a paint context that covers the entire app bar, and draws over the background of the appbar but below its content (hopefully - it seems to be below the title at least so I assume it's below everything else too). The background color is still drawn under the appbar so if your gradient is somewhat transparent you'll probably want to set the backgroundColor to Colors.transparent.

Here's the code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(GradientAppBar());

class GradientCheatingBorder extends Border {
  const GradientCheatingBorder({
    this.gradient,
    BorderSide top = BorderSide.none,
    BorderSide right = BorderSide.none,
    BorderSide bottom = BorderSide.none,
    BorderSide left = BorderSide.none,
  }) : super(top: top, right: right, bottom: bottom, left: left);

  const GradientCheatingBorder.fromBorderSide(BorderSide side, {this.gradient})
      : super.fromBorderSide(side);

  factory GradientCheatingBorder.all({
    Color color = const Color(0xFF000000),
    double width = 1.0,
    BorderStyle style = BorderStyle.solid,
    Gradient gradient,
  }) {
    final BorderSide side =
        BorderSide(color: color, width: width, style: style);
    return GradientCheatingBorder.fromBorderSide(side, gradient: gradient);
  }

  final Gradient gradient;

  @override
  void paint(
    Canvas canvas,
    Rect rect, {
    TextDirection textDirection,
    BoxShape shape = BoxShape.rectangle,
    BorderRadius borderRadius,
  }) {
    if (gradient != null) {
      canvas.drawRect(
        rect,
        Paint()
          ..shader = gradient.createShader(rect)
          ..style = PaintingStyle.fill,
      );
    }

    super.paint(
      canvas,
      rect,
      textDirection: textDirection,
      shape: shape,
      borderRadius: borderRadius,
    );
  }
}

class GradientAppBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GradientAppBarState createState() => _GradientAppBarState();
}

class _GradientAppBarState extends State<GradientAppBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(
      home: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
            largeTitle: Text("Title"),
            border: GradientCheatingBorder.fromBorderSide(
              BorderSide.none,
              gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.black, Colors.white]),
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
              [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  height: 500,
                ),
                Divider(),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.black12,
                  height: 500,
                ),
                Divider(),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.lightBlue,
                  height: 500,
                ),
                Divider(),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.lightGreen,
                  height: 500,
                ),
                Divider(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It may be ugly, but it is damn clever! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**you can try this**

```
flexibleSpace: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                end: Alignment.centerRight,
                colors: [
                  Colors.red,
                  Colors.blue
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: there is no flexibleSpace in the CupertinoSliverNavigationBar.